# yocto recipe for an application that uses dlib and opencv

Tags: opencv, yocto, dlib, recipe

I made a yocto recipe for dlib and also I added opencv package in `local.conf`.
Now I want to make a recipe for an application that uses dlib and opencv libraries. I tried the following recipe, but when I try to build it with `bitbake application`, it throws me some errors. 
`dlib recipe`:

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/davisking/dlib"

LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://docs/docs/license.xml;md5=2e6ff4080dcb217d4d300b90e9aabb5b \
                    file://examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=57eee82829ed297e23d84de5f905afee \
                    file://examples/video_frames/license.txt;md5=127ee508b60a6be9dea8af3b441993dc \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/davisking/dlib.git;protocol=https"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "3b794540baeabbcd033b544230401967106d5483"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

do_compile() {
        cd ${S}
        cd dlib
        mkdir build
        cd build
        cmake ..
        sudo make install
}

FILES_${PN} += "/${base_prefix}"
inherit cmake
```

`application recipe`:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://application.cpp;md5=df22013877ba7d830e9993ae1d77d724"

SRC_URI = "file://application.cpp"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
        ${CXX}  -std=c++11 -O3 -L${libdir}/libdlib.a -I${includedir}/dlib/ -lpthread -lX11  application.cpp ${LDFLAGS} `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o application
}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 application ${D}${bindir}
}
```

some `errors` when I try `bitbake application`:

```
| application.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm[_ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm]+0x1a8): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
| application.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib11pinv_helperINS_9matrix_opINS_8op_transINS_6matrixIdLl3ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEEEEEKNS3_INT_4typeEXsrSA_2NCEXsrSA_2NRENSA_16mem_manager_typeES6_EERKNS_10matrix_expISA_EEd[_ZN4dlib11pinv_helperINS_9matrix_opINS_8op_transINS_6matrixIdLl3ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEEEEEKNS3_INT_4typeEXsrSA_2NCEXsrSA_2NRENSA_16mem_manager_typeES6_EERKNS_10matrix_expISA_EEd]+0x4fc): undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
| application.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib28get_serialized_frontal_facesB5cxx11Ev[_ZN4dlib28get_serialized_frontal_facesB5cxx11Ev]+0x8e9c): undefined reference to `dlib::base64::~base64()'
```

What can I do in order to slove this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dlib recipe to

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/davisking/dlib"

LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://docs/docs/license.xml;md5=2e6ff4080dcb217d4d300b90e9aabb5b \
                    file://examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=57eee82829ed297e23d84de5f905afee \
                    file://examples/video_frames/license.txt;md5=127ee508b60a6be9dea8af3b441993dc \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/davisking/dlib.git;protocol=https"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "3b794540baeabbcd033b544230401967106d5483"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DDLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON"
```

Then in your application recipe

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://application.cpp;md5=df22013877ba7d830e9993ae1d77d724"

inherit pkgconfig 
DEPENDS += "dlib opencv"

SRC_URI = "file://application.cpp"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3 -I${STAGING_INCDIR}/dlib -pthread application.cpp -o application ${LDFLAGS} `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lX11 -ldlib
}

do_install() {
        install -D -m 0755 application ${D}${bindir}/application
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have some errors for the dlib recipe. When I try to build dlib recipe I have the following error: `do_package: QA Issue: dlib: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package`. The full error can be found here: https://pastebin.com/4NUZm3b0

Comment: Also I mention that I use Yocto Project v2.2 Morty

Comment: Should I add `FILES_${PN} += "/${base_prefix}"` ? After I added this line the recipe builds without errors. But now I have some errors for the application recipe. When I try to build application recipe I have the following error: ` fatal error: ../dlib_include_path_tutorial.txt: No such file or directory`. The full error can be found here: https://pastebin.com/RLTjapmf

Comment: Is there any other files except .cmake files in /usr/lib/cmake/dlib? I think append `FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/cmake/dlib"` to the recipe should works for you. But I wonder it may need to update cmake option.

Comment: @Kai Thank you for your answer. The Dlib recipe is building fine now, without errors. But the problem is now the Application recipe. It seems that it doesn't find the Dlib library. These are the errors from building the application recipe:  https://pastebin.com/RLTjapmf

Answer (score 0):

You might want to update the license in the recipe otherwise the example provided by Khem will return a warning. The Boost License is:

```
LICENSE = "BSL-1.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2"
```